# Yoast Breadcrumb Error Message

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

I tried to edit the yoast-breadcrumbs.php to get rid of the "blog" link using this:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/yoast-breadcrumbs-how-can-i-remove-blog-link

When it didn't work I reverted back to the original code but now I am getting the following error message when I try to active Yoast breadcrumb plugin:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare yoast_breadcrumb() (previously declared in /home/creative/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/inc/wpseo-functions.php:96) in /home/creative/public_html/wp-content/plugins/breadcrumbs/yoast-breadcrumbs.php on line 311

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the plugin **Wordpress SEO** installed which has breadcrumbs included. It looks like you cannot install the breadcrumb plugin also. Use the breadcrumb feature included in **Wordpress SEO** plugin.

Answer (score 1):

#### From yoast.com => [Yoast Breadcrumbs – WordPress Breadcrumbs](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/breadcrumbs/)

> *This plugin has been succeeded by my new [WordPress SEO plugin](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/). The*
> *info below is still valid, but you’d better try the new plugin, **which***
> ***has even cooler WordPress breadcrumbs!***

So, as **@roofdog** pointed out and if you have already [`WordPress SEO plugin`](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/)...

...remove the old `breadcrumbs plugin` and use/modify the new one (that you already have)